# Removing a combination of characters from a string

Tags: python

So I have some tickers that look like this:

```
DISTIL PLC 0.1P
ITACONIX PLC 1P
LIGHT SCIENCE TECHNOLOGIES HOLDINGS ORD 1P
CERILLION PLC 0.5P
CROSSWORD CYBERSECURITY PLC 0.5P
PAN AFRICAN RESOURCES PLC 1P
INLAND HOMES PLC 10P
SERICA ENERGY PLC USD0.10
GENEDRIVE PLC 1.5P
GATTACA PLC 1P
BIDSTACK GROUP PLC 0.5P
C4X DISCOVERY HOLDINGS PLC 1P
THINKSMART LIMITED ORD NPV (DI)
BRAND ARCHITEKTS GROUP PLC 5P
MTI WIRELESS EDGE LD ORD ILS0.01
PETROTAL CORPORATION COM SHS NPV (DI)
QUANTUM BLOCKCHAIN TECHNOLOGIES PLC 0.25P
HURRICANE ENERGY PLC 0.1P
DIURNAL GROUP PLC GBP0.05
VICTORIA PLC 5P
TRUFIN PLC 91P
DEWHURST GROUP PLC 'A'NON.VTG ORD 10P
BONHILL GROUP PLC 1P
BRAVE BISON GROUP PLC 0.1P
RAMBLER METALS & MINING PLC 1P
ARROW EXPLORATION CORP. COM SHS NPV (CDI)
VALIRX PLC 0.1P
VERTU MOTORS PLC 10P
MINOAN GROUP PLC 1P
VERSARIEN PLC 1P
TAVISTOCK INVESTMENTS PLC 1P
OVOCA BIO PLC EUR0.125 (CDI)
KERAS RESOURCES PLC 1P
EQTEC PLC EUR0.001 (CDI)
ELIXIRR INTERNATIONAL PLC 0.005P
ARMADALE CAPITAL PLC 0.1P
ECHO ENERGY PLC 0.25P
AGRITERRA LD ORD 10P
LONGBOAT ENERGY PLC 10P
FEEDBACK PLC 0.25P
PIPEHAWK PLC 1P
ARC MINERALS LD ORDS NPV (DI)
PROVEXIS PLC 0.1P
QUIZ PLC 0.3P
TINTRA PLC 1P
GYG PLC GBP0.002
```

Everything after the PLC I want removed e.g. 1P, GBP0.002 ect

I've made a for loop with the different combinations as you can see below, but I cant seem to get it working correctly.

```
misc = (
        "GBP0.01", "0.01P", "1P", "GBP1", "50P", "0.3P", "0.0", "0.02", "0.002P", "0.4P", "0.001P", "2.5P", "0.2P",
        "10P", "0.8P","PLC 1P", "0.025P","025P"," 0.00" ,"0.5P", "USD0.01", "2P", "5P","0.0","0.","GBP00001","025P","20P","GBP005")


for i in misc:
    for d in old:
        q = d.replace(i, "")
        if q not in old:
            new.append(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the way you are going about solving this is overly complicated.

Instead consider:

```
data = [
     'DISTIL PLC 0.1P',
     'ITACONIX PLC 1P',
     'LIGHT SCIENCE TECHNOLOGIES HOLDINGS ORD 1P',
     'CERILLION PLC 0.5P',
     'CROSSWORD CYBERSECURITY PLC 0.5P',
     'PAN AFRICAN RESOURCES PLC 1P',
     'INLAND HOMES PLC 10P',
     'SERICA ENERGY PLC USD0.10',
     'GENEDRIVE PLC 1.5P',
     'GATTACA PLC 1P',
     'BIDSTACK GROUP PLC 0.5P',
     'C4X DISCOVERY HOLDINGS PLC 1P',
     'THINKSMART LIMITED ORD NPV (DI)',
     'BRAND ARCHITEKTS GROUP PLC 5P',
     'MTI WIRELESS EDGE LD ORD ILS0.01',
     'PETROTAL CORPORATION COM SHS NPV (DI)',
     'QUANTUM BLOCKCHAIN TECHNOLOGIES PLC 0.25P',
     'HURRICANE ENERGY PLC 0.1P',
     'DIURNAL GROUP PLC GBP0.05',
     'VICTORIA PLC 5P',
     'TRUFIN PLC 91P',
     'DEWHURST GROUP PLC ''A''NON.VTG ORD 10P',
     'BONHILL GROUP PLC 1P',
     'BRAVE BISON GROUP PLC 0.1P',
     'RAMBLER METALS & MINING PLC 1P',
     'ARROW EXPLORATION CORP. COM SHS NPV (CDI)',
     'VALIRX PLC 0.1P',
     'VERTU MOTORS PLC 10P',
     'MINOAN GROUP PLC 1P',
     'VERSARIEN PLC 1P',
     'TAVISTOCK INVESTMENTS PLC 1P',
     'OVOCA BIO PLC EUR0.125 (CDI)',
     'KERAS RESOURCES PLC 1P',
     'EQTEC PLC EUR0.001 (CDI)',
     'ELIXIRR INTERNATIONAL PLC 0.005P',
     'ARMADALE CAPITAL PLC 0.1P',
     'ECHO ENERGY PLC 0.25P',
     'AGRITERRA LD ORD 10P',
     'LONGBOAT ENERGY PLC 10P',
     'FEEDBACK PLC 0.25P',
     'PIPEHAWK PLC 1P',
     'ARC MINERALS LD ORDS NPV (DI)',
     'PROVEXIS PLC 0.1P',
     'QUIZ PLC 0.3P',
     'TINTRA PLC 1P',
     'GYG PLC GBP0.002']

for d in data:
    print(d.split("PLC")[0])

# or with list comprehension:
data = [d.split("PLC")[0] for d in data]
```

Or if you want to preserve that `PLC` in the string, you could use regex:

```
import re
data = [
     'DISTIL PLC 0.1P',
     'ITACONIX PLC 1P',
     'LIGHT SCIENCE TECHNOLOGIES HOLDINGS ORD 1P',
     'CERILLION PLC 0.5P',
     'CROSSWORD CYBERSECURITY PLC 0.5P',
     'PAN AFRICAN RESOURCES PLC 1P',
     'INLAND HOMES PLC 10P',
     'SERICA ENERGY PLC USD0.10',
     'GENEDRIVE PLC 1.5P',
     'GATTACA PLC 1P',
     'BIDSTACK GROUP PLC 0.5P',
     'C4X DISCOVERY HOLDINGS PLC 1P',
     'THINKSMART LIMITED ORD NPV (DI)',
     'BRAND ARCHITEKTS GROUP PLC 5P',
     'MTI WIRELESS EDGE LD ORD ILS0.01',
     'PETROTAL CORPORATION COM SHS NPV (DI)',
     'QUANTUM BLOCKCHAIN TECHNOLOGIES PLC 0.25P',
     'HURRICANE ENERGY PLC 0.1P',
     'DIURNAL GROUP PLC GBP0.05',
     'VICTORIA PLC 5P',
     'TRUFIN PLC 91P',
     'DEWHURST GROUP PLC ''A''NON.VTG ORD 10P',
     'BONHILL GROUP PLC 1P',
     'BRAVE BISON GROUP PLC 0.1P',
     'RAMBLER METALS & MINING PLC 1P',
     'ARROW EXPLORATION CORP. COM SHS NPV (CDI)',
     'VALIRX PLC 0.1P',
     'VERTU MOTORS PLC 10P',
     'MINOAN GROUP PLC 1P',
     'VERSARIEN PLC 1P',
     'TAVISTOCK INVESTMENTS PLC 1P',
     'OVOCA BIO PLC EUR0.125 (CDI)',
     'KERAS RESOURCES PLC 1P',
     'EQTEC PLC EUR0.001 (CDI)',
     'ELIXIRR INTERNATIONAL PLC 0.005P',
     'ARMADALE CAPITAL PLC 0.1P',
     'ECHO ENERGY PLC 0.25P',
     'AGRITERRA LD ORD 10P',
     'LONGBOAT ENERGY PLC 10P',
     'FEEDBACK PLC 0.25P',
     'PIPEHAWK PLC 1P',
     'ARC MINERALS LD ORDS NPV (DI)',
     'PROVEXIS PLC 0.1P',
     'QUIZ PLC 0.3P',
     'TINTRA PLC 1P',
     'GYG PLC GBP0.002']

for d in data:
    print(re.search(r'.*\sPLC|.*', d).group(0))

#or with list comprehension
data = [re.search(r'.*\sPLC|.*', d).group(0) for d in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got that right, "DISTIL PLC 0.1P" should become "DISTIL", and so on for the rest. As @mkrieger1 suggested, the simplest solution is to use split on 'PLC', like this: `new = [s.split('PLC')[0].strip() for s in old]`.
`.strip()` is just to remove spaces at the end, so you get "DISTIL" instead of "DISTIL "

You might need a further split in case `old` is a single string and not a list. For instance, in case you have something like this:

```
old = "DISTIL PLC 0.1P
ITACONIX PLC 1P
LIGHT SCIENCE TECHNOLOGIES HOLDINGS ORD 1P"

old_list = old.split('\n')
new = [s.split('PLC')[0].strip() for s in old_list]
```